# How many triangles can a connected graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges have?

Tags: graph-theory

I am very interested in the maximum number of triangles could a connected graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges have. For example, if $m\leq n−1$, this number is $0$, if $m=n$, this number is $1$, if $m=n+1$, this number is $2$, and if $m=n+2$, this number is $4$.

Comment: If we omit the restriction of connectedness, see this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823481/number-of-triangles-in-a-graph-based-on-number-of-edges
Also note that we can achieve connectedness with a few number of edges, so the order of magnitude of the number of triangles is the same without your restriction.

Comment: @Soltész I want to get a good bound in terms of $m-n+1$.  I believe this number could be bounded by $(m-n+1)^2$ roughly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a bound and since it is very long, I wrote it an answer, may be it can be helpful.

Let $G$ be a connected graph with $n$ vertices and $m$ edges. Suppose the eigenvalues of this graph are $\lambda_1\geq \lambda_2\geq\ldots\geq\lambda_n$. We know that $\sum{\lambda_i^3}=6\Delta_G$, where $\Delta_G$ counts the total number of triangles of the graph $G$.

Also,we have:

$$\lambda_1\leq\sqrt{2m-\delta(n-1)+\Delta(\delta-1)}.$$

Since your graph is connected, we can set $\delta=1$ and obtain:
$$\lambda_1\leq\sqrt{2m-n+1}.$$

So we have:

$$\Delta_G\leq\frac{n}{6}(2m-n+1)^{\frac{3}{2}},$$

as you wanted in your comments.

Actually, you can get more information from this method since we exactly know when the upper inequalities which I used are equality for which graphs. You can search for "SHARP UPPER BOUNDS OF SPECTRAL RADIUS OF GRAPHS" or similar keywords.

Comment: Thanks, this method is very helpful. This bound can be easily improved as $\Delta_G\leq\frac{n-1}{6}(2m-n+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}$.

Comment: This can be further improved with $\Delta_G \leq m^{3/2}$.

Answer (score 3):

This question (together with massive generalizations) is answered in [I. Rivin's 2001 paper.](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0111106)

Comment: The paper seems interesting. It has some trivial results, but one up vote for the very nice style of writing.